# Asp.net/ Jquery. postback of an aspx page and JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page with a gridview and a panel with some controls like text box and drop down list.

The panel is shown with a jquery function that shows or hides it with slow motion effect.

The problem is:
When I press a search button to bind some data to grid view, the postback event is prompted by pressing this button. If the previous panel was visible, after the postback, it isn't visible anymore, so it returns in the initial state.

I would like to maintain the panel visible after the postback event.
How can I solve this problem?

This is the jquery code to show or hide panel:

```
Function ShowHidePanel(){
$['#variablePanel'].slideToggle('linear')

}
```

This is the button that call the jquery function:

```
<button onclick=ShowHidePanel();return false> Click to show/hide Panel</button>
```

This is the panel to show or hide that contais controls like text box etc.:

```
<div id="variablePanel"> 
</div>
```

This is the code of update panel to postback only the grid view :

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="sm" runat="server"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="up" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView id="gw" runat="server" >

</GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

thanks

Comment: will any code be provided, or you expect to get the **abstract answer** as well?

Comment: Hard to help without code, but maybe you could use ASP.Net Ajax panels to update the postback of the grid, leaving the panel that you show or hide outside the Ajax update panel...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. As Suggested, I edited the question with a part of code

Comment: where did you created your javascript function? It should be within head tag

Comment: It's not in a head tag. This function is in the asp content element. Do you think that that's the problem?